# WP 8.1 Capability

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, capability

When I'm running my WP 8.1 app I got a message "id_cap_isv_camera capability is required". I've added this capability to WMAppManifest.xml:

```
    <Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MAP" />
    </Capabilities>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: You are trying to build WP8.1 app, there is also *packageappx.manifest* file - open it -> capabilities -> try to add *WebCam* and other that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Add this after ID_CAP_MAP: Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA" />